# How to copy elements of a list into a new one [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Well, basically I'm making a "Music player menu" and I need to create a function that search music in the catalogue by name, author or genre and if one of these elements matches that specific song, copy all those elements and add them to a playlist

This is the function to add a song to the music catalogue:

```
Cat = [] #This is the music catalogue list

def AddSong():
  songs = [] #This is where I'm storing the songs
  print('--- Add song ---') 
  while True:
    name = input('Songs name: ')
    author = input("Author: ")
    genre = input("Genre: ")
    length = input("Song length: ")
    songs.append(name)
    songs.append(author)
    songs.append(genre)
    songs.append(length)
    Cat.append(songs)
    return
```

**The added song looks like this, ['Crazy train', 'Ozzy Osbourne', 'Heavy metal', '4:56']** in the Cat list

This is the function to create a Playlist:

```
Play = []
    if len(Cat) > 0:
         print('--- Add a playlist ---')
    else:
         print("Error: There's not songs")
         return     
    namep = input("Please, introduce a name for your new playlist: ")
    Play.append(namep)
    Cata()
    i = int(input("Please, introduce the correspondent number to add the song to the playlist"))
    Play.append(Cat[i-1])
    if len(Cat) > 0:

        print('=== Available Playlist  ===')
    for p in Cat:
      # print(str(n)+'. '+lista[0])
      print(f'{"Playlist: "}{Play[0]}')
      print(f'{"Name: "}{p[0]}')
      print(f'{"Author: "} {p[1]}')
      print(f'{"Genre: "} {p[2]}') # <--- formatted string 
      print(f'{"Length: "}{p[3]}')


    return True
```

I managed to add all the information of a song to a playlist through indexes, but I need to know if there is a way to add a song to a playlist if the name, author or genre that the user enters matches a song in the catalogue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
keyword = input("search keyword")
for song in Cat.songs:
    if keyword in song:
        Play.append(song)
```

Comment: Yup, it solves my whole code, thank you! and don't worry about the indent, you were truly helpful.